# I don't know what to make an array or list of if/else statments

Tags: c#

this is a code i have been trying to write pretty straight forward to some users but i am only learning how to use C#. What i am trying to do is input a list of employees and assign numbers to them so that the code will read the employee number and assign the employee name to the correct number when entered. So my question is would i be better making an array of string and int or a case of if/else statements?

```
        int number;
        string 
        //this is the initial part of the program to define wether the use is a general user or an admin user

        Console.WriteLine("SWC Production - Access Security\npress 1 for user access \npress 2 for admin login\n\n");
        number = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        if (number == 1)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\nPlease enter your employee number\n");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        else if (number == 2)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\nPlease enter your admin number\n");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        else 
        {

            Console.WriteLine("\nError!!!\nPlease Try Again\n");

        }

        Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: I would suggest using an array which then you can reference employees by a number between [].  For example "empArray[1]" to get the second employee in the array.  Work on creating the array and if you have issues, post the code you've tried here and we can help you further.

Comment: why don't you make a simple switch case what's the problem here..? also you could create a Dictionary<int, int> or Dictionary<string,string> there are several approaches you could create a List<ClassEmployee> with 2 fields etc....

Comment: thanks for the feedback people greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

In most applications users would be stored in some permanent storage like a database. I can see this is some sort of proof of concept or learning project, so some sort of UserManager class that can perform a search for a user based on an employee number is propably a good way forward and will more closely resemble an actual application implementation.

That UserManager could internally use a dictionary or some lookup list for a more generic approach.

Or you could just use a switch case right from the start, it kinda depends on what your goal is with this.